# How to Open WebView links in Browser in Xamarin Cross-Plotform Application for both iOS and Android

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, cross-platform

i am new to Xamarin,
I am developing Xamarin Cross-Plotform Application and which is working fine for both iOS and Android.

i have one View in my Portable Class Library Project and this View is supporting Both iOS And Android, in that i am using WebView and i am loading that WebView with an External Html Page,
Here i have an issue Like in that External Html page we have Some Hyperlinks, and when we click on that hyperlink it is get opened in app but i need this should open with a browser.

I am loading my webview in Portable Class Library Project, like below

```
mywebview.Source = new UrlWebViewSource { Url = myurl };
```

Can Any one help me out how to open webview hyperlinks in Browser for both iOS and Android.

I Tried with the following block of code, but it is not working

```
private void mywebview_Navigated(object sender, WebNavigatedEventArgs e)
{
    string jscall = "var d = document.getElementsByTagName('a'); for (var i = 0; i < d.length; i++) { if (d[i].getAttribute('target') == '_blank') { if(d[i].href.includes('?')) {d[i].href = d[i].href + '&target=blank';} else {d[i].href = d[i].href + '?target=blank';}}}";
    Loadfromweb.Eval(jscall);
}

private void mywebview_Navigating(object sender, WebNavigatingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Url.ToLower().Contains("target=blank"))
    {
        var uri = new Uri(e.Url);
        Device.OpenUri(uri);
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
    else
    {
        e.Cancel = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: your solution looks correct, but will only work on links with target=blank.  Is that what you intend?  Have you stepped through it in the debugger to check the behavior?

Comment: Yes Jason, I have the following in my external Html page
<a target="_blank" href="tryit.asp" >Click Here</a>

Comment: if your code you are using "blank", not "_blank"

Comment: so i need to change   "_blank" to "blank" in my Html page?

Comment: I'm saying that what you are testing for in your code and what the html in your page actually contains do not match.  And I don't think that the target attribute is even included in the Url property of WebNavigatingEventArgs.   I really suggest you break out the debugger and step through your code

Comment: Actually the webview Navigated and Navigating events are not firing when i try to debug with break point Can you Please help me out

Comment: Check out where these events should be fired, or post the relevant portion of code that should do so

Comment: Thank you Jason, You Saved my Day it is working fine now